# www Rewrite rule + Password Auth Combo, causes non-www urls to return 401/404 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, authentication, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've just noticed a problem with non-www urls for my domain:

when I type `http://mydomain.com` (without www),
the browser tries to go to `http://www.mydomain.com/401.shtml`, and returns a 404.

The website is currently password protected (from the root),
and I have this .htaccess rule, whice I set to redirect all non-www to www:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!www\.)(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.%1/$1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

The thing is, that I had applied the password protection and the above rule a few days ago,
Whereas this problem is occuring only now. (I remember going to the url without www, and it worked fine).

**Another very strange thing:**

On FF and IE10, the no-www Url doesn't work either for the root (`http://mydomain.com`) nor for any pages indside (`http://mydomain.com/page.php`) - getting that 401/404; On Chrome, only the root doesn't work, while inside pages get redirected to the www url, and show up fine.

**EDIT:**

Removing each of either the .htaccess rule or the authentication solve this, but I'm not looking for removing them.

Thanks

Comment: Part of your problem is you're probably running into a caching issue. Make sure to clear your cache when your test rewrites. Chrome will do that. If you use inspect elements on Chrome, set it to disable caching while debugging tools are open.

Comment: just cleared the cache from IE and FF, problem still persists...

Comment: It seemss like the combination of the authentication and the rewrite rule is causing this: when I cancel either one, it resolves.
since I can't change the password rule as it is standard, is there something wrong with my current .htaccess rule?

Answer (score 1):

Try add this line

ErrorDocument 401 default

to your .htaccess